# Creating symlinks for tmux

Tags: macos, tmux

Helo,

I've been trying to install tmux on a mac and I get the following

```
**Lukes-Air:Haskell Luke$ brew install tmux**
Warning: tmux-2.1 already installed, it's says it's not linked
```

So I try

```
**Lukes-Air:Haskell Luke$ brew link tmux**
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/tmux/2.1... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/bash_completion.d/tmux
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d is not writable.
Lukes-Air:Haskell Luke$
```

Then I try

```
**Lukes-Air:Haskell Luke$ sudo brew link tmux**
Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew link'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
```

I also tried

```
**Lukes-Air:Haskell Luke$ brew link --overwrite tmux**
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/tmux/2.1... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/bash_completion.d/tmux
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d is not writable.
```

... Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out

```
I did chmod 777 /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
```

and then brew link tmux worked!